# Trash bin empty automatic

Tags: 14.04, trash

My trash bin empties automatic and I lost some valuable files and I don't remember I ever changed something in the settings, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

nautilus->edit->preferences.

Unchek the last option "include a delete command that bypasses the trash"

Comment: hmmm the settings are right but when i delete something i get this error " can't be put in the trash. Do you want to delete it immediately?"

Comment: I have the same exact problem - "cant be put in the trash" for every single thing I delete.